# Random number generation guaranteeing uniqueness over time

Tags: random, unique, uniqueidentifier, unique-index

I created a counter that goes up from 0 to 9999 until it resets again. I use the output of this counter as a value to make unique entries. However, the application needs to find its last created number each time the application is restarted. Therfore I am looking for a method which avoids any sort of object storage and relies solely on random number generation.

Something like:

```
int randomTimeBasedGenerator() {
    Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
    int num = r.nextInt() % 9999
    return num
}
```

But what guarantee do I have that this method generates unique numbers?  And, if not, how long would it remain unique?  Are there any study papers I can look into for this sort of scenario?

Random number generation would be an elegant solution for my situation, if I can at least guarantee it won't repeat within a couple of weeks or months. But random number generation would be useless in my case if no such guarantee exists.

Comment: Is it important that you get a sequence of increasing integers? If not, you can use a UUID to generate guaranteed unique values (which are strings, though, or, if you will, very large integers).

Comment: Thanks @Thilo, are UUIDs guaranteed for uniqueness even if the application is restarted/redeployed?  And can I extract just the last 4 values and still maintain uniqueness or would that then be lost?

Comment: yes, they are unique without any external coordination. What do you mean by "last 4 values"? If you are asking if you can just shorten the UUID to a few digits, then: No, that will lead to collisions.

Comment: Read up on the Birthday paradox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack  With 65536 different random numbers (and you have even fewer), you only need 300 numbers to get a duplicate with 50% probability.

Comment: Do you really need the number to behave in a random fashion? An ever increasing value would also be unique, does it have to look random?

Comment: Good point @LasseVågsætherKarlsen , in truth no - that's not needed.  I'm currently weighing the possibility of using System.currentTimeInMillis() and truncating it to the last 10 bits since that can be our workable maximum size.  That should allow for uniqueness, provided a value isn't generated twice in the same millisecond.

Comment: Most database engines (all?) have a way of generating a sequence of numbers. Depending on the maximum range and your rate of inserting data this may be more than enough for your needs. Are you rolling your own system without the use of a database?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have no guarantee that the return value of a random number generator remains unique. Random number generators generate *unique sequences* of numbers, not unique numbers. Random numbers will *always* repeat themselves, sooner or later.

As suggested by @Thilo, UUIDs are unique numbers. But an even better approach in your case might be to set up a lightweight database (sqlite will do) and add a record to a table with incremental id's. It is not possible to keep track of a process without storing values somewhere.

Comment: This answer is not only unhelpful, it's also wrong. For a real answer, check out this thread: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/339125/acceptable-to-rely-on-random-ints-being-unique